# How is this a JavaScriptSerializer CA2322 violation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If we create a JavaScriptSerializer object with a specific resolver then that is restricting the deserializing object variables and it is [CA2322](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2322) violation. But how is the below mentioned code a violation?

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class ExampleClass
{
    public JavaScriptSerializer Serializer { get; set; }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string str)
    {
        return this.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
    }
}
```

Ref Code : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2322#violation-1)

Can someone explain why the above mention code is a violation?

Comment: Is there anything special you didn't understand from the link you've posted? That seems quite well explained.

Comment: @imsmn, Violation states that if we initialize the resolverwith SimpleTypeResolver we should remove that. But, in the mentioned example we did not initialize with any resolver so it should not be any violation right?

Comment: No, because the public property could be assigned hence introducing the security problem. Check my answer. If the ExampleClass.Serializer could be set with a malicious class that could execute undesired code (attacker would control what to decode and set a malicious deserializer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a public `Serializer` property you get the risk of getting assigned a serializer you do not control and that is a security problem.

Quote from the [CA2322 violation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2322) link you provided:

> Insecure deserializers are vulnerable when deserializing untrusted data. An attacker could modify the serialized data to include unexpected types to inject objects with malicious side effects

That is the reason the proposed solution is:

```cs
public class ExampleClass
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string str)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return s.Deserialize<T>(str);
    }
}
```

**Reason**: It is intended to make it the `s` a private variable (not assignable with an untrusted serializer).

Other problematic code would be:

```cs
public class ExampleClass 
{
    // this is more subtle
    private static readonly JavaScriptSerializer Serializer { get; set; }      

    public T Deserialize<T>(string str)     
    {         
        return this.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(str);     
    }

    // You have no control over the constructor arguments, here you would introduce the bug
    public void ExampleClass(JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
         this.Serializer = serializer;
    } 
}
```

That is why the proposed solution for that second scenario would be not only `readonly` but also assigned on the declaration:

```
private static readonly SimpleTypeResolver Simple = new SimpleTypeResolver();
```

Comment: `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class ExampleClass
{
    private static readonly JavaScriptSerializer Serializer { get; set; }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string str)
    {
        return this.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
    }
}`
How is the above mentioned code a CA2322 violation even though i made it private variable?

Comment: Even if it is private variable this object can be modified by other functions. Is this the reason? @Cleptus

Comment: @AkhilReddyBandi The "scenario 2" forces the variable as `readonly` to get rid of the warning. So the compiler knows it cannot be overriden

Comment: So, why was it a violation then? Any reason?