# Is it safe method against sql injection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

Is it safe method for C# against sql injection?

```
string sqlDeclare = $"DECLARE  @number nvarchar(MAX)  SET @number = '%{sNumber}%' ";


string sqlFilter = "";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number))
{
   sqlFilter += $" and [table].[number] like @number ";
}


 string sql = sqlDeclare + " SELECT [table].[*] ";
 sql += " WHERE [table].[state] = 0 and [table].[column1] <> 3 AND [table].[id] > 0  ";

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlFilter))
 {
     sql += sqlFilter;
 }
 sql += " order by datein";
```

P.S. I can't use Parametr.Add()

Comment: NO!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding SQL injection without parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters)

Comment: the _only_ safe protections against SQL injection are _parameterised statements_ and whitelisting for those _very few_ cases where you can't use them.

Comment: *I can't use Parametr.Add()* - then you'll struggle to be safe from injection. Tell us more about why you can't

Comment: *`DECLARE  @number nvarchar(MAX)`* - declaring a string called number is probably a really good indicator that a better name is possible

Comment: @CaiusJard, Because I have been provided with a wrapper function for sqlCommand that takes a string parameter(

Comment: Post your wrapper function

Comment: @CaiusJard, i have no source code. Signature like this Public DataTable Execute4Table(string query)

Comment: @Sergey No, would not work, you did not pass to `Execute4Table` the parameter so the database would complain about a undefined parameter, the function you are calling should have an overload similar to `Execute4Table(string commandText, params SqlCommand[])` but... You already said you have no access to the source code.

Comment: The `Execute4Table` function is fundamentally flawed by *forcing* you to comingle code and data. You'll "never" be safe from SQL Injection whilst you continue to use it.

Comment: @Cleptus meant to say SqlParameter[] rather than SqlCommand[], I think

Comment: Indeed, cannot edit now, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If you're truly forced to use this function you'll have to do the best you can with checking the inputs. I added some advice to the end of my answer

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe method for C# against sql injection?

if `sNumber` actually was a numeric type, like int or decimal then I'd say "maybe" because it's pretty hard to inject SQL into a number, but at the end of the day, all you've done is change from concatenating a string value directly into an sql query, which is the classic fail:

```
"SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = " + str
```

into putting a string value into a db variable that you then use in an sql. It means the select query won't be the place where the injecting is done, but it just moves the injection point earlier:

Think what happens when `sNumber` is a value like `'; DROP TABLE students;--`

```
DECLARE  @number nvarchar(MAX)  SET @number = '%';
DROP TABLE Students;--%' 
SELECT ...
```

---

If you truly are restricted to using this function (it needs throwing away, tbh) then you'll have to do your best at preventing injection by sanitizing the input. In this case you say you're expecting a document number like `2-12` so your C# should look like

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(userInput, @"^\d+-\d+$"))
  throw new ArgumentException("Bad input value, expecting document number like 2-12");

var dt = Execute4Table($"SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = '{input}');
```

In a general sense, it would be clunky, but you could perhaps do some wrapper function that takes N parameters and serializes them to JSON, then you pass them to sqlserver as a json string and get SQLS to deser them into N parameters that you use in the query. The two serializers should encode any user provided values in such a way that they are interpreted as data rather than code. You could also do a similar thing with base64 if your sqlserver is too old for json. To some extents this isn't much different to replacing all ' with '' but with a set/deser approach you're handing off responsibility for that encoding to a well tested library, which is probably the only thing you can do if you are rather hamstrung by this method you're forced to use

Comment: Yeap, thanks. I already checked this). Now i must fix it.

Comment: Javascript deserialization also incorporates its own [weird things security wise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968265/2265446) but this answer is a good one given how the question evolved (from "_is this code safe?_" to "_how to mitigate SQLi?_". Upvoting your question yet maintining mine because ultimately making other API secure your code is not totally secure (yet it is likely a good mitigation and far better than securing it yourself)

Answer (score 2):

It would be safe if you type check the `sNumber` variable and you made sure it has no string dangerous data (your `sNumber` could have `0';TRUNCATE TABLE [table];--` and that would be SQL Injection). If you check if your `snumber` is integer, you would be safe on your string interpolation.

**Otherwise it would not be safe**. It is best to avoid string interpolation/string concatenation.

```cs
int checkedNumber;
if (Int32.TryParse(out checkedNumber, sNumber))
{
    string sqlDeclare = $"DECLARE  @number nvarchar(MAX)  SET @number = '%{sNumber}%' ";
    string sqlFilter = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number))
    {
       sqlFilter += $" and [table].[number] like @number ";
    }
     string sql = sqlDeclare + " SELECT [table].[*] ";
     sql += " WHERE [table].[state] = 0 and [table].[column1] <> 3 AND [table].[id] > 0  ";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlFilter))
    {
        sql += sqlFilter;
    }
    sql += " order by datein";
}
```

Comment: Yeap, but all parametrs can be string. My number it's a document number and he can be like 1-21 or something else.

Comment: Then it is not safe, period.